# Problems with std::cin.fail()

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

I am writing some code to read from the terminal with cpp but for some reason it crashed after running out of numbers. From what I have read online I should be able to check if `std::cin` was successful by using `std::cin.fail()` but it crashes before.

The code I am running is

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x{};

    while (true)
    {
        std::cin >> x;
        if (!std::cin)
        {
            std::cout << "breaking" << '\n';
            break;
        }
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with the input:

```
test@test:~/learn_cpp/ex05$ ./test
1 2
1
2
^C
```

I end up having to ctrl+c out of the program. Version info:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: A simpler version of that loop is `while (std::cin >> x) std::cout << x << '\n';`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in your input causes `cin` to set the fail bit. Hence, the `while (true)` will just keep going. You can enter a letter, or something which is otherwise not an `int`, which will set the fail bit, and cause the loop to break.

Note that a new line will be ignored for this purpose.

If you know that all your input will be on a single line, then you can use `std::getline` to read in the entire line, and then `std::stringstream` to read the integers from that line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int x{};
    std::string buff;
    std::getline( std::cin, buff );
    std::stringstream ss( buff );
    while ( ss >> x ) {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there a cin exception thrown when there's nothing to read?

Comment: No, there's always something to read, unless you hit eof; which, on command line, is something like ctrl D, always forget what exactly it is.

Comment: So how could one approach this if the value for the final user input is uncertain? Is it possible to read the endline of the eof and exit conditionally on that?

Comment: You could read a full line using `std::getline`, pass the result of that to a `std::stringstream` and use that to get the integers.

Comment: @MortenNissov, I've added an example.